# Refresh DIV with data from same page

Tags: php, ajax, variables, html, refresh

Basically I have a foreach loop bringing in data from an array of products in a database which include price etc.. The data is pulled down first by a simple mySQL SELECT query. Which is then stored in an associative array.

I want to count the number of items that get displayed on the page. I know how to count the items in the array but I'm going to be filtering which ones get displayed on the page via urls and would like to just count how many get actually displayed.

I had the idea to just have a variable and + 1 everytime the foreach loop ran but the trouble is I need to echo the number before the loop runs.

Here is my loop:

```
    <h2>Title</h2><h5><? echo $numberofproducts; ?> products</h5>
    <? 
    $numberofproducts == 0;
    foreach(get_products() as $product){
    $numberofproducts++; 
    // display product info
    ?>
```

Is there a way to update the h5 tag after the loop has finished running via AJAX? Without the need for another php file with one line in it?

Comment: can you elaborate on why you can't access `get_products()` before the `h5`?

Comment: I can but if I count everything in the array before it's filtered wont that just return the number of items in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go like this:

```
<?php $products = get_products(); ?>

<h2>Title</h2><h5><?php echo count($products); ?> products</h5>
<?php 

    foreach($products as $index => $product){

        //you may use $index as the progressive loop counter

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works, but if I have an if statement depending on what is in the url, e.g. products.php?cat=3, so the loop only runs if there are any products with "cat" equal to 3. wont this still count the items that dont equal 3 in the array.

Comment: @MikeZange well pass a `$cat` parameter to you `get_products()` function in order to filter your results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#div_id').find('h5').html(".$numberofproducts.");</script>";
```

Comment: Couldnt get this to work for some reason code looks sound, just wouldnt find <h5> :S

Comment: `#div_id` should be the id the div you're dealing with.

Comment: Yes, #div_id must be the id of the div you're using. Also, try to change <h5> to just h5

Answer (score 0):

You could also just run the loop twice:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<?php
  $numberofproducts = 0;
  $products = get_products();
  foreach($products as $product){
    ++$numberofproducts; 
  }
?>
<h5><?php echo $numberofproducts; ?> products</h5>
<?php
  foreach($products as $product){
    // display product info
  }
?>
```

I'm presuming the collection is fairly small otherwise you wouldn't be fetching all of them first and then filtering in the for loop.

Further, if you are dynamically changing the page content/list with javascript then hook in a count of the (visible) elements in the list after you do the filtering and then update the number in the h5.